# Magento 2.3.2 Unsupported operand types indexer

Tags: php-7.2, magento2.3.2

I'm using a custom module in magento 2.3.2

In one of my php files I have this code:

$queryResult =  $client->search($requestQuery);

```
    $offset = $queryResult['hits']['total'];
    if (!$offset) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->load($index - $offset + 1, $offset - 1, $lower);
```

But this:

```
return $this->load($index - $offset + 1, $offset - 1, $lower);
```

returns error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

What I am doing wrong in syntax?